# How do without permissions taggable friends

Tags: php, facebook, permissions

I have a script for Facebook is working to compile a profile picture friends in one image

video: http://fhamatoor.com/fb/vid/

But he calls the images using taggable_friends Can you make it brings images using user_friends or public_profile

This is script code is responsible for fetching images and merge them

```html
 $gameid3 = uniqid();
 $_SESSION['gameid3'] = $gameid3;
 // getting friends list
 $friends = $fb->get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name,id,picture.width(140).height(140)&limit=100');
 $friends = $friends->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
```

Please help me

Comment: You can use `/me/friends` instead – but that will only give you friends that are users of the same app. (And that is all your app is _supposed_ to work with nowadays; mis-using `taggable_friends` for something like in this example is not allowed.)

Comment: He tried but did not work
`taggable_friends` need approval and this is the problem

Comment: You won’t _get_ approval for this, because this is not an acceptable use case for `taggable_friends`.

Comment: For this I want to change it
And image acquisition in another way

Comment: I already told you which way there is.

Comment: I tried and did not benefit
I do not know the reason

Comment: It's like taggable_friends Only work to the application managers

Comment: You can experiment http://fhamatoor.com/fb/en/gameid3

Comment: Of course it only works for admin users (or other users with a role in the app), _because_ you did not get it approved.

Comment: Is `/me/friends` also needs approval?

Comment: No, it only needs `user_friends` permission from the app user. (And from their friends as well.)

Comment: The problem, my friend
It only calls friends who use the application
And in the case of his inability to find friends not be able to provide image

Comment: Yes, that is what I said from the very beginning. And also, that this is a deliberate restriction introduced by Facebook – you app is _supposed_ to have access to as little information as possible about people that are not using. So users of your app that want to create such a picture, would need to invite their friends to join that app and give it permission first.

Comment: I understand
Thank you :)

Comment: Sir, Are there any other way to bring pictures of friends
There are many applications use this and she did not get approved
Example: http://ar.nameguess.com/play/who-are-your-best-friends-forever/?step=2#_=_